# Windows 'net use' usage

Tags: windows, command-line, smb

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with credential scanning of a Windows 2012 Server using Nessus and one of the [troubleshooting](https://community.tenable.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-Credential-scanning-on-Windows) step is to run the following command from an elevated command prompt.

`net use \\x.x.x.x\ipc$ "" /user:""`

It says its trying to see if we can access the IPC$ share without a username. This is understood. However, I'd like to know what is the meaning of the `""` between `ipc$` and `/user:`

Answer (score 1):

It's the user's password.
Where "" means there's no password for the user you specified.
You can drop this part, and type the password manually.

check `net use /?` for more.